# Problems with Windows 7 RC

Tags: windows-7

I recently installed Windows 7 RC from microsoft website. Lately I've been having some strange problems with the OS which I suspect is due to some corrupt system files.

- With Aero peek feature (taskbar), when I place the mouse over the open windows (or other open programs) the peek displays for only less than a second. Earlier it used to display the peek for as long as I held the mouse pointer over the peek area.
- When idle, the PC doesn't display the screen saver and doesn't turn off the display, both configured rightly.

I have done the following to fix the problem, but to no avail.

- Repair install of Windows 7 (upgrade option). Problem persisted.
- Complete install on Windows 7. As soon as I booted the new installation, the problem showed up.
- I have reinstalled the display drivers.

The PC in question is Dell Vostro 1000 notebook PC.
I'm using the same OS with my Desktop PC but its running absolutely fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why not go ahead and install the RTM version.  It's out and probably solves some of your issues.

Comment: How to get one? Is RTM still available? I didn't see any such links on Windows7 website.

Comment: If you're a MSDN / TechNet subscriber you can download via the subscriber links.  If not you can buy it via retail methods.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to try out the RTM version for free, you can always download the [90 Trial of Windows 7](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/cc442495.aspx?ITPID=sprblog) which is on the Microsoft website. This will let you test the software on your hardware with the final version of the product. After installing this version,  you should be able to see if any of the errors that you are experiencing have been corrected.

Hope this helps some.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at your keyboard or mouse (more likely mouse).  The things that will cause both the peek to disappear and not cause the screen to blank is moving the mouse.  I have seen some mice that "drift" when just sitting still.  It might be subtle so you may not see it with the naked eye or it could be going a pixel up and then one down.

Comment: Yes I thought about it myself but the problem occurs even when not using the mouse (i.e using trackpad).

Comment: Try disabling all the USB connected input devices and then switch keyboards just to be sure.  I am assuming the issue does not appear on XP?